# How to get Out of Office Status of User in SharePoint Workflow

Tags: sharepoint, outlook, workflow, exchange-server

I've a requirement where I need to read the Out of Office status of a user in SharePoint Workflow (Visual Studio) before creating a Task for that person. If the person is out-of-office the workflow should not create a Task.

Is it possible to check the Out of Office status of the user using any API in SharePoint?

Comment: Which Exchange server are you working with?

Answer (score 1):

The user's Out of Office (OOF) status and notifications are stored in Exchange, not SharePoint, so there isn't a SharePoint API to gather this information, however, Exchange Web Services does expose this information. [This blog post](http://gsexdev.blogspot.com/2011/11/using-mailtips-in-ews-to-get-oof-out-of.html) includes sample code for calling Exchange 2010 to query for OOF status.